# How to access adapter class textview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

This is my adapter class

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyHolder> {

List<ListData> listData;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<ListData> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
}

@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);

    return new MyHolder(view);
}


public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
    ListData data = listData.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(data.getName());
    holder.message.setText(data.getMessage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listData.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView message, name, badge;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        message = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_message);
        badge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.badge);

    }
}
```

This is my Fragment class.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle b) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, group, false);
    recyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.rview);
    badge = view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("message");
    hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                UserDetails userdetails = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserDetails.class);
                String name = userdetails.getName();
                String nameCaps = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
                String message = userdetails.getMessage();

                if (hashMap.containsKey(name)) {
                    if (!hashMap.get(name).equalsIgnoreCase(message)) 
                       hashMap.remove(name);
                        hashMap.put(nameCaps, message);
                    }
                } else
                    hashMap.put(nameCaps, message)
            }
            list = convertHashToObjectList(hashMap);
            RecyclerViewAdapter recycler = new RecyclerViewAdapter(list);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerview.setAdapter(recycler);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

private ArrayListconvertHashToObjectList(HashMap hashMap) {

```
    ArrayList<ListData> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        listData.add(new ListData(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
 return listData;
}
```

I want to use the textview badge in fragment class. How to access the adapter class textview in fragment class. When i instantiated the textview in Fragment class it shows the error null object reference.

Comment: share more details with code

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Is the fragment going to show after clicking an item from the recyclerview?

Comment: No.I just set visibility to the textview from fragment class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code for same:

```
  for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                UserDetails userdetails = dataSnapshot1.getValue(UserDetails.class);
                String name = userdetails.getName();
                String nameCaps = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
                String message = userdetails.getMessage();

                if (!updateMessage.containsKey(nameCaps)) {

                    updateMessage.put(nameCaps,false);
                }
                if (hashMap.containsKey(name)) {
                    if (!hashMap.get(name).equalsIgnoreCase(message)) {

                        hashMap.remove(name);
                        hashMap.put(nameCaps, message);
                      updateMessage.put(nameCaps,true);

                    }
                } else
                    hashMap.put(nameCaps, message);



            }
            list = convertHashToObjectList(hashMap);

            RecyclerViewAdapter recycler = new RecyclerViewAdapter(list,updateMessage);
```

"updatemessage" is a hashmap which holds the changes in message.

Answer (score 0):

The way to update some items in a `RecyclerView` is by updating your data set, then notifying the adapter that the data set has changed.

So first you need to update the data for badge in your `List<ListData>`.
Then you need to notify change for the adapter. Here's an example

The code goes inside your adapter

```
public void updateData(List<ListData> newData) {
    listData = newData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And make sure in your `onBindViewHolder()` to set the value of badge if exists.

Comment: In your fragment when you want to update badge textView

Comment: How to use. Please explain

Comment: I assume you have some sort of event that updates your "badge" value, is that correct? and at this point you want to reflect new value on UI, show me code snippet for where you do that badge update

Comment: see the edited code.When a new message arrives from database it checks the user name, When same user send message twice it shows a badge near his name in recycler view but when a new user send message the badge do not show.How can do this

Comment: Okay one last question before i suggest an answer, what does ListData represent? a message? or a user row? and can every ListData have its own badge?

Comment: Listdata is a model class.It get and set the name and message